# Differentiating a function, then re-integrating the same function?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was trying to wrap my head around differentiation under the sign of integration, so I was reading [this note](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf).

In page 16, we want to derive $$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\log(1+tx)}{1+x^2}dx$$

I think I understand up until the author obtained $F'(t)$, but then he introduced $y$?

Actually, before I read the answer, I tried to derive it myself, but I stopped at $$F'(t) = \frac{t\arctan(t)}{1+t^2} + \frac{\log(1+t^2)}{2(1+t^2)}$$ and thought: do I have to integrate this with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $t$?! So I gave up and looked at the answer, but the author actually completely evades this by saying $F(t) = \int_{0}^{t}F'(y)dy$!

Now my understanding of how the solution should be is this: we want to obtain $$\int_{0}^{\text{thing}}f(x,\text{thing}) \ dx$$

right? So we differentiate with respect to $thing$ and should then integrate back also with respect to $\text{thing}$, right? So if we are going to introduce $y$ into the expression, then the upper limit of the integration should be $y$ too, right? (in which case the substitution is pretty useless). How is this mix between $y$ and $t$ valid?

Sorry if the question is unclear but I'm quite confused..

Comment: You don't want to integrate with respect to t if t is a bound of the integral. The author used a dummy variable y to get around t being in the integral bounds.

Comment: @user401445 think this integral has already been solved on MSE if you're just interested in the solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136298/a-generalization-for-serrets-integral-int-0a-frac-ln1ax1x2dx

Comment: by taking the derivative: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1869241

Comment: @AbhishekVangipuram is it invalid to integrate with respect to something which is in the integral bound? I remember in physics we used to integrate (e.g.) displacement from (say) 0 to a general displacement $s$ when the constant of integration was also s... So were we just being lazy by not changing the name of the variable? (I feel like I now understand my original question. I was making a fuss over nothing.. well that's the power of confusion :) )

Comment: @bjorn93 Well thanks but I wanted to understand this specific solution because I felt $y$ surprised me

Comment: @user401445 you can differentiate with respect to $t$, you just have to use Leibniz's rule correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: Yes, in your physics class I believe that there wasn't really any need to change your variable of integration, even if you should have. That is all the author did to make the integral make more sense.